# Adding infowindows - google maps API

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

So essentially I'm having a problem with adding info windows onto a map, in the google maps api.

The markers work just fine so I'm not going to paste the code, but what doesn't work is the info window. I can get the info window to load up something such as "hi", but when I want to access an object which I have declared outside the function, it says it is undefined.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(javascriptLocations){
    info.setContent(javascriptLocations[i]["name"]);
    info.open(worldMap,this);
});
```

I've declared javascriptLocations further up in the script here:

```
<?php

$phpLocations = $getInfos->getLocations();
$jsonLocations = json_encode($phpLocations);
echo "javascriptLocations =".$jsonLocations.";";

?>
```

and it loads up just fine, it's simply when I want to access it inside the function it comes up with defined. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

remove javascriptLocations as a parameter of the listener callback, or call it event or whatelse. In your code the javascriptLocations variable inside the function is the event object because is overwritten!

Comment: I've removed it... but it doesn't seem to make a difference? It still just doesn't pop up with an info window.

Comment: pastebin whole code, it seems that `javascriptLocations[i]` is undefined, to debug: `console.log(javascriptLocations);` as first instruction of the callback function. Is `i` defined inside a loop? If so the callback will be called with the same last value of `i`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0u6cyiTp there's the pastebin. Yes [i] is defined in a loop, of which the code is in: http://pastebin.com/eSEArTCJ - the first bit works, it's just the info window which doesn't

Comment: the problem is that `i` is accessible inside the callback function, but when the value is not passed when the callback is defined, so when the callback is called `i` has looped till its last value which is `javascriptLocations.length`, and `javascriptLocations[javascriptLocations.length]` is undefined!, See here what happens, is the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/tm3zK/

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for the help. Instead of setting the content to the object, I set it to the title of the marker. Thanks anyway!